# Does this random variable built from log normals have a recognizable distribution?

Tags: probability-distributions

Let $X_t$ be a standard Brownian motion, and $\lambda$ and $\alpha$ are positive constants.  Consider the random variable:
$$ \int_0^t \lambda e^{\lambda u + \frac{\alpha u X_t}{t} - \frac{\alpha^2 u^2}{2t}} du$$

Does this guy have a standard distribution?  Thanks!